# CircularProgressIndicator causes 100% CPU on emulator or iOS simulator

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Should I block the animation for the CircularProgressIndicator? Such as?
This is the code:

```
Widget _loading() {
 return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      "Vai nelle informazioni per avere ulteriori consigli",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 32,
    ),
     CircularProgressIndicator(
     backgroundColor: AccentPColor,
    ),
  ],
 );
}
```

Comment: Are you only showing `CircularProgressIndicator` in your widget tree?

Comment: CopsOnRoad yes...

Comment: Can you post minimal reproducible code?

Comment: Ok done  . . .

Comment: I meant full reproducible code starting with `main()` method, since I am not sure where are you using that `_loading` method. Currently I am not on computer, so may not test it now, but it will also be beneficial for others to answer.

Comment: [CircularProgressIndicator causes 100% CPU on IOS simulator](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21445)
[Circular Progress Indicator CPU Heat Bug on Android Emulator](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17793)

Still not fixed for so long time, these should get some attention.

Comment: Another open one here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13203